# how does this inner-class static scoping magic work?

Tags: c#, static, scope

```
public class Outer
{
    public  class Inner
    {
        public static string OtherValue { get { return SomeValue; } }
    }

    public static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }
}
```

Why does the above compile? Isn't SomeValue out of scope in Inner and need qualifying with `Outer.SomeValue`? Isn't the above essentially the same as the below (which won't compile)?

```
public class Outer
{
    public class Inner
    {
        public static string OtherValue { get { return Outer.SomeValue; } }
    }

    public static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }
}
```

What `static` magic is going on here?

Comment: It is very confusing for you to name a nested class which is **not** a subclass "sub", and an outer class which is **not** a superclass "super"!

Comment: Good point, cut/paste from another question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner class inherits part of the outer class' scope. So members in `Outer` are accessible from within `Sub`, but they still belong to the outer class, which is why `Sub.SomeValue` does not work.

The technical term is *lexical scope*, and it means that a variable's scope covers the 'lexical' block it is in, that is, it is accessible anywhere within the source code block in which it is defined, including sub-blocks, regardless of run-time ownership. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29#Lexical_scoping.

Languages like Javascript, Lisp, Haskell, and most other languages aimed at functional programming make extensive use of lexical scope, and it is closely related to other FP concepts such as partial function application, closures and currying.

Once you've gotten used to it, it can be an incredibly useful (and elegant) tool.

Comment: It's all flooding back to me now :)

Answer (score 7):

It is like:

```
public class Super
{
    public class Sub
    {
        public static string OtherValue { get { return Super.SomeValue; } }
    }

    public static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }
}
```

With `Super` holding the static `SomeValue`

---

It is more clearly displayed like:

```
public class Super
{
    public static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }
}

public class Sub
{
    public static string OtherValue { get { return Super.SomeValue; } }
}
```

Now with `Sub` and `Super` being `public` their static properties are visible to all within their shared scope. And as @jonskeet pointing out, the compiler will search for the best fit for `SomeValue` looking in the class `Sub` first since the value is used in that class.

Now something like this would not compile:

```
public class Super
{
    private static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }
}

public class Sub
{
    public static string OtherValue { get { return SomeValue; } }
}
```

However,

```
public class Super
{
    private static string SomeValue { get { return "Outer"; } }

    public class Sub
    {
        public static string OtherValue { get { return SomeValue; } }
    }
}
```

the above is fine due to the nesting of the classes.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy, I thought my code would explain the difference. However, I will update to better explain. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

`Sub` is a nested class of Super, so any member of `Super` is in the scope of Sub. However, these "inherited" members are not members of `Sub`, so `Sub.SomeValue` is not valid. The compiler translates `SomeValue` into `Super.SomeValue`.

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with the meaning of *simple names*, which is dictated by section 7.6.2 of the C# 4 spec:

> Otherwise for each instance type T (section 10.3.1), starting with the instance type of the immediately enclosing type declaration and continuing with the instance type of each enclosing class or struct declaration (if any):
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if a member lookup (section 7.4) of I in T with K type arguments produces a match:
>
>   - [... not applicable here ...]
>   - [... not applicable here ...]
>   - Otherwise, the result is the same as a member access (section 7.6.4) of the form `T.I` [...]

So in other words, the compiler first checks whether `Sub.SomeValue` is valid, finds it isn't, then it checks `Super.SomeValue`, and finds it is.